# Eclipse not hitting breakpoints in IE

Tags: java, eclipse, internet-explorer

I am trying to debug an app engine project.  When I test my code in chrome my break statements hit and I can step through my code in eclipse.  When I test the same page in IE, the break statement never hits and I get a response without ever executing the break.  What is going on here?

Comment: Perhaps, in IE, the code in question isn't being executed?

Comment: I have the breakpoint at the beginning of my page controller.  The page couldn't be viewed if the code wasn't executed.

Comment: This is when I'd be kicking tires. Am I *positive* my Chrome/IE setups are identical (besides the browser)?  Am I sure I'm hitting the same server?  If I throw an exception in that page handler, do I see it both places?

Comment: All of this is on my local server so I don't see how they could be hitting different servers.  Sometimes multiple instances of the server are created but I checked this by stopping the server and making sure I get no page found, which I do.  Are there any settings in IE that tell the server not to hit breakpoints? I just removed Disable script debugging in advanced options.  Is there something like this for server debugging?

Comment: So I discovered the breakpoints only fire if I had them set before I launch IE.  If I launch IE then set them or change the breakpoints, they do not fire.  This is TERRIBLE!!! Any explanation to why it works this way?

Comment: Are you talking about a breakpoint set in Java code executing at server-side? If the page is shown in IE, and the code is not executed at server-side, it probably just means that IE reads the page from its cache.

Comment: @JB this seems to be the case, adding $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); to my page give me normal functionality